# What causes my Nikon D40 to shoot darker photos when shot sideways?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, digital

I have a Nikon D40 that functions impeccably, the only issue that I found was that it shoots darker pictures when shot sideways. Doesn’t matter what mode, ISO, focal length, etc. They all come out darker when shot sideways. I don’t know if this is a lens problem, but the lens that I use (and the only one I have) is a AF Nikkor 28-80mm. The lens, from my experience, doesn’t have any problems either, but again I am still not sure if it is what’s causing the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Which metering mode are you using - and if it's not full manual, does the issue still occur with full manual metering? Similarly, if you could add example photos to your post that would be helpful - you'll have to add the shutter speed / aperture / ISO separately because Stack Exchange's image hosting service strips the metadata. Thanks!

Comment: Any kind of polarizing filter involved?

Comment: How does the metadata compare?